# Changing color of bins in ggplot2 histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the color of the bins, based on group, of one of the ggplot histograms. I see the outline of the bins is specified in `geom_histogram(color="black")` but am not sure how to change the fill color of the bins themselves.

Below is the code:

```r
ggplot(
  Size_Comparison_Proper_Without_Juveniles\_, 
  aes(x=values, fill=group)
  ) +
geom_histogram(
  position="dodge", 
  alpha = 1, 
  bins=30,
  color="black")+
labs(
  title='Total Length at Earthworm Sites \\n vs Total Length at Earthworm-Free Sites',
  y='Count',
  x='Snout-Vent Length (mm)')+
theme(
  legend.position="top",
  text = element_text(size=15))+
scale_fill_discrete(
    name="Group", 
    labels=c("With Earthworms - Total Length","Without Earthworms - Total Length"))+
geom_vline(
    xintercept=38.39, 
    color="royalblue4",
    size=1.5,
    linetype="longdash")+
geom_vline(
    xintercept=39.62583,
    color="orange", 
    size=1.5,
    linetype="longdash")
```

Thank you!!

[image]

I have only tried playing around `aes(color="")` and `geom_histogram(color="")`

```
    structure(list(EW = c(34, 42, 34, 34, 34, 39), noEW = c(36, 35, 
39, 35, 36, 38), values = c(34, 42, 34, 34, 34, 39), group = c("Tot_ew", 
"Tot_ew", "Tot_ew", "Tot_ew", "Tot_ew", "Tot_ew")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You can set argument `fill="black"  inside geom_histogram().

Comment: I would like the fill to be two different colors based on group. Ie dark blue for group1 and light blue for group 2.

Comment: Is it possible you provide your data? You can run `dput(Size_Comparison_Proper_Without_Juveniles\_)` or at least a few rows `dput(head(Size_Comparison_Proper_Without_Juveniles\_))` . You run the command and copy the output as a code to your question.

Comment: Certainly. I edited the question with some lines of the data. It is simple 2 columns, one with 'values', the other with 'group' (which is the treatment).

Comment: I see, here is the dput(head(data) lines. I am only using the columns 'values' and 'group'.

Comment: ok. at the end add this argument `+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("dark blue", "light blue")`

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for your help, Bloxx.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bloxx pointed out, you can use `scale_fill_manual`. However, you don't need both, so we can replace the other `scale_fill_discrete`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = values, fill = group)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "dodge", alpha = 1, bins = 30, color = "black") +
  labs(title = 'Total Length at Earthworm Sites \\n vs Total Length at Earthworm-Free Sites',
       y = 'Count',
       x = 'Snout-Vent Length (mm)') +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        text = element_text(size = 15)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = "Group",
    labels = c(
      "With Earthworms - Total Length",
      "Without Earthworms - Total Length"
    ),
    values = c("dark blue", "light blue")
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 38.39, color = "royalblue4", size = 1.5, linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 39.62583, color = "orange", size = 1.5, linetype = "longdash")
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(EW = c(34, 42, 34, 34, 34, 39, 35, 36, 37, 38, 
40), noEW = c(36, 35, 39, 35, 36, 38, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40), values = c(34, 
42, 34, 34, 34, 39, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40), group = c("Tot_ew", 
"Tot_ew", "Tot_ew", "Tot_woew", "Tot_woew", "Tot_woew", "Tot_ew", 
"Tot_ew", "Tot_ew", "Tot_woew", "Tot_woew")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```